# Unable to read .json file

Tags: javascript, dojo

I referred the example [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/fromJson.html#introduction).

Here is my code in Dojo:

```
dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};

console.log('loading...');                   // shows up in console

require(['dojo/_base/xhr']), function(xhr){
    xhr.get({
        url: "js/data.json",
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(data){
            console.log('about to load...');    // does not show in console
            console.log(data);                  // does not show in console
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

I believe this is fairly simple. What could be possibly wrong here? Is the module `dojo/_base/xhr` not loading?

**EDIT:** There is no error in the console.

**EDIT 2:** Actually, the module path was incorrect. I fixed it and now I am getting two errors:

```
GET http://localhost:81/dojo_assignment/dojo/_base/xhr 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught Error: xhrFailed
```

Comment: *"Is the module dojo/_base/xhr not loading?"* How can we know? You could find that out by putting a `console.log` statement in the callback (*not* the Ajax callbacks).

Comment: @FelixKling Please see the edits. Where exactly do you men to put the `console.log`? Sorry, I am new to Dojo.

Comment: For example before `xhr.get()`. *edit:* But if you are still getting the 404 error, then it doesn't look like the module is actually found.

Comment: @FelixKling I put in `console.log('check')` before `xhr.get()`. It did not show up in the console.

Comment: Then it looks like the path to the module is still wrong. Since I don't know where the file is located on your filesystem, you have to figure out the correct path yourself.

Comment: @FelixKling The path to `xhr.js` is `C:\xampp\htdocs\dojo_assignment\dojo\_base` and that to my javascript file is `C:\xampp\htdocs\dojo_assignment\json_to_gridx\js`

Comment: Hmm, it's stange that it is trying to load `xhr`, not `xhr.js` (look at the error). That should normally not happen (or did you make a typo?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, remove the bracket `)` after your module array.

For example:

```
require(['dojo/_base/xhr'], function(xhr) {
    // ...
});
```

That should normally work, as you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/SV7j9/) (it's giving an error because the JSON file doesn't exist, not because the module doesn't exist).

---

**Note**: If you're trying to read a static local resource, a better approach would be the following:

```
require(["dojo/text!js/data.json", "dojo/json"], function(myData, json) {
    var myJSON = json.parse(myData);
});
```

---

**Note**: Configuring `dojoConfig` AFTER you loaded the Dojo AMD loader (the script loading `dojo.js`) won't work. You need to initialize it before your load the script, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myApplication.js"></script>
```

Comment: I corrected the typo. But the JSON is still not showing up. I am getting `SyntaxError {} ` in `dojo.js`. When I expand the error, it shows numerous elements pointing at `dojo.js:15`. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: If you get that error, close and open your console/developer tools (F12). Normally you should get extra information now where the `{}` stood.

Comment: I liked your suggestion in Note 1 but for that I got an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
http://localhost:81/dojo_assignment/json_to_gridx/js/json_to_gridx.js
Line 6` EDIT: The JSON data shows up in the GET request, in Firebug, but the error is still there.

Comment: That means your JSON is invalid, try to validate your JSON file at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I corrected the JSON, it is still throwing an error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' var myJSON = json.parse(myData);`

Comment: Ah, works now! You are awesome! Come to Goa, I will buy you a beer! :)